# Update ProgressBar UI object from Task Parallel Library

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

Basically i would like to update ProgressBar UI object on the FormMain (WindowsForm). I am using .NET 4.0

Here are  the code in the Form1.Designer.cs

```
namespace ProgressBarApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {         
        private System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar curProgressBar;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CustomProcess theProcess = new CustomProcess();
            theProcess.Process();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the definition of CustomProcess.cs

```
namespace ProgressBarApp
{
    class CustomProcess
    {
        public void Process()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Task ProcessATask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000); // simulating a process
                    }
                 );

                Task UpdateProgressBar = ProcessATask.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
                    { 
                        // how do i update the progress bar object at UI here ?
                    }
                 );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should update progressbar inside ProcessATask otherwise it will be filled up instantly. Because you use independent tasks to update progressbar.

Comment: The UpdateProgressBar is executed After the ProcessATask has been completed. This is defined using .ContinueWith . I need to wait until the previous task has been completed, so that i can report that this task is all completed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) to do this. To use it for a `Task`, you need to create a `TaskScheduler`, which you can do by calling [`TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx):

```
Task UpdateProgressBar = ProcessATask.ContinueWith(antecedent =>
    { 
        // you can update the progress bar object here
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

This will work only if you call `Process()` directly from the UI thread.

Comment: @Mark You can't use `Invoke()` directly from the `CustomProcess` class from the question, since it's not a `Control`.

Comment: I thought like `targetControl.Invoke(invokationDelegate);`, using the Invoke-method of the targeted control, which I thought was the whole point of that method. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4):

How about using [System.Reactive.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

**[UPDATE]**

```
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //private System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar curProgressBar;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CustomProcess theProcess = new CustomProcess();
            var x = Observable.FromEventPattern(theProcess, "TaskCompleted");
            curProgressBar.Maximum = 4;
            x.Subscribe((a) =>
            {
                curProgressBar.Value = ((CustomProcess)a.Sender).Counter;
            });
            theProcess.Process();
        }

    }

    class CustomProcess
    {

        public int Counter { get; set; }
        public event EventHandler TaskCompleted = OnTaskCompleted;

        private static void OnTaskCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((CustomProcess)sender).Counter++;
        }
        public void Process()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                Task ProcessATask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000); // simulating a process
                    }
                 );
                var awaiter = ProcessATask.GetAwaiter();
                awaiter.OnCompleted(() =>
                {
                    TaskCompleted(this, null);
                });
            }

        }
    }
}
```