# How do I stop a progress bar when the last task has finished?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a UI program that updates slow-loading items. I managed to get the items to load in parallel, and show each item as soon as it has finished loading. However, I want to show a progress bar while loading, and hide it once all items are loaded.

```
private void refreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        Task.Factory
            .StartNew(() => DoNonUiwork(item))
            .ContinueWith(antedecent =>
            {
                UpdateUI(antedecent.Result);
                if ( /* if what? */ )
                {
                    progressBar1.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
}
```

I could remember all my tasks and use `Parallel.WaitAll()` on them, but then I'd be block the UI thread, which is Not Nice.

I could setup a homebrew sync mechanism - maybe a counter that starts with `int itemsToUpdate = Items.Count()`, and then `/* if what? */` becomes `--itemsToUpdate== 0`. It works, but doesn't feel very Task-like...

Is there a Tasks-native way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just increment a counter when you start a task, decrement it when it is done.  When it reaches 0 then the PB should disappear.

Comment: You can use workaround as suggests @HansPassant, but remember that your tasks run in difference threads.

Comment: No, the counting is guaranteed to run on the same thread.  If it doesn't then updating the PB can't work either.

Comment: I would use something like @Alex Filipovici soultion in the below link: [Alex Filipovici ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946839/update-progressbar-ui-object-from-task-parallel-library) This make the Task similar to async\await pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Task.WhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall.aspx) method for this purpose. or use [TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321473.aspx) and then you can marshall the control to UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `Parallel.WaitAll()` in *yet another task*.

Answer (score 0):

You could try firing off another Task that does Task.WaitAll() and notifies your UI after.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the parent task.
2. Attach all tasks to parent.
3. In parent continuation hide progress bar.